# Error: global queries do not support strong consistency

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I insert an Entity:

```
datastore.save({
    key: datastore.key(['Users', 'bob']),
    method: 'insert',
    data: [
        {
            name: 'email',
            value: 'bob@gmail.com',
            excludeFromIndexes: false
        }
    ]
}, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('insert was a success');
    }else{
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Then I want to query the user by email:

```
var query = datastore.createQuery('Users').filter('email', 'bob@gmail.com');
    datastore.runInTransaction(function(transaction, done) {
        transaction.runQuery(query, function(err, entities) {
            if (!err) {                
                //insert another thing into the datastore here ...

        }else{
                console.log('err = ' + err);
                transaction.rollback(done);
                return;
        }

        });
});
```

But I get the error:

> global queries do not support strong consistency

I saw I can't modify the consistency in node in the docs, so how do I query?

Answer (score 1):

When you query against Datastore, these operations by default are [eventually consistent](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency). This means results that you have recently written may not show up in your query.

You can make sure that Datastore queries are strongly consistent by adding an [you can only perform strongly consistent queries.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency), which restricts the query to a single Entity Group (the unit of consistency in Datastore).

When you are running in a transaction, [you can only perform strongly consistent queries.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency) Since you are running in a transaction but not specifying an ancestor filter, you get this error.

Comment: How about if I am using gcloud-nodejs. How can i specify I want these queries to be strongly consistent? In the docs it says Read consistency cannot be specified in gcloud-node. Why is this? Will there be support for this in gcloud?

Comment: Sorry I am now a little confused haha. This is my scenerio: I have a KIND called 'user'. Entities here have no parents or children. I need to query some users and if they are found I need to 'lock' these entities. I then need to query more entities, but this time I need to query entities in a KIND called friends (again none of these have parents or children). I know need to update the USER entities and I need to INSERT a couple more Friend Entities. This must be atomic, all  or nothing. Using gcloud-node is this possible?

Comment: If you don't have a parent you can't query in a transaction. The read_consistency option can only be used to reduce your consistency level -- if you are running a strongly consistent query you can ask for eventual consistency for performance reasons but not the other way around.

Comment: If you don't want parents the only workaround would be to setup your user's key names to be what you are querying for. For example if user A adds user B as a friend, in a txn you can get A, get B (and fail and rollback if B doesn't exist), then add B to user A's friend list. You just have to do a get/lookup to find B instead of a query.

Comment: Thank you  for the information and the possible workaround.